# Problem loading an tfidf object with pickle

Tags: python, pickle

I have an issue with pickle:
from a previous job, I created an sklearn tfidfvectorizer object and I saved it thanks to pickle.
Her is the code I used to do it :

```
def lemma_tokenizer(text):
     lemmatizer=WordNetLemmatizer()
     return [lemmatizer.lemmatize(token) for token in 
word_tokenize(text.replace("'"," "))]

punctuation=list(string.punctuation)
stop_words=set(stopwords.words("english")+punctuation+['``',"''"]+['doe','ha','wa']) 
tfidf = TfidfVectorizr(input='content',tokenizer=lemma_tokenizer,stop_words=stop_words)

pickle.dump(tfidf, open(filename_tfidf, 'wb'))
```

I saw that if i wan't to load the this tfidf object thanks to pickle, I need to define the function "lemma_tokenizer" before. 
So I create the following python script named 'loadtfidf.py' to load the tfidf object :

```
import pickle
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize


def lemma_tokenizer(text):
    lemmatizer=WordNetLemmatizer()
    return [lemmatizer.lemmatize(token) for token in word_tokenize(text.replace("'"," "))]

tfidf = pickle.load(open('tfidf.sav', 'rb'))
```

if I run this script the object is well loaded and everything goes well!

BUT then, I create another python script named 'test.py' in the same directory of 'loadtfidf.py' where I simply try to import loadtfidf:

```
import loadtfidf
```

And when I try to run this one line I have the following error :

"""Can't get attribute 'lemma_tokenizer' on module '**main**' from '.../test.py'"""

I really don't understand why... I don't even know what to try to fix this error... can you help me to fix it?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: The reference to that function in the pickle file is specifically to `__main__.lemma_tokenizer`.  When you import it from another file, it's not accessible by that name anymore - it's `loadtfidf.lemma_tokenizer`.  I believe that you need to do `from loadtfidf import lemma_tokenizer` so that the function actually gets defined in the `__main__` namespace.

Comment: Thank you very much for your message, it helps me a lot! I was able to solve my problem! I created another file with only the function lemmatizer and I call it in test.py before importing loadtfidf.py it's ugly but it works ;)